# Looping VBA macro to copy cells based on a condition with an offset and paste under another table

Tags: vba, excel

I want to:

- Search control column D, copy the cell value from column B corresponding to XXXX in the column D (minus 2 columns offset).
- Paste this cell value in a cell with 1,1, offset from the last used cell in column F.
- Loop until there is no more XXXX and go to another sheet.

I am missing the part for copying cells next to XXXX.

```vb
Sub Copy()

    Dim LR As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim SA As String
    
    With ActiveSheet
        LR = .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To LR
            If .Range("D" & i) Like "XXXX" Then
                'MISSING LINE TO COPY A CELL 2 COLUMNS LEFT FROM XXXX
                Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1) = SA
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: if your `.Range("D" & i) Like "XXXX"` is true then the cell would be `.Range("B" & i)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this gets you anywhere.  It finds an instance of XXXX in column D, using your code, and then searches for the last used row in column F and places the value retrieved from column B after that.

Here is a 1 row and 1 column offset starting from the last entry in column F so that way the code would not overwrite the value since the last used value in column F would never change otherwise.

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copy()

Dim LR As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim lastUsedRow As Long

With ActiveSheet

    ' gets last used row in column F
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lastUsedRow = .Range("F" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    LR = .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To LR
        If .Range("D" & i) Like "XXXX" Then

           ' prints the value starting with a 1,1 offest to the last used row in column F
            Cells(lastUsedRow + 1, 7).Value = Cells(i, "B").Value

            lastUsedRow = lastUsedRow + 1

        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Program output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you mate. It doesnt work yet but on a  good trail. I changed Sheet1 to ActiveSheet. Also I changed Cells(lastUsedRow + 1, 6) to Cells(lastUsedRow + 1, 7) because I need it to find last used row on F and then put it under it but in column G. Now, the thing that doesnt work is it doesnt stack them. I end up only with the last entry with XXXX next to it because the code copies them all one over another instead of under. Could you please amend the code to stack all the values in column B corresponding with XXXX in column D one after another so I have them all and not just one.

Comment: I see what Ive done. It works when its +1,6. But I need it to find the last used row in column F and print with the offset of 1,1 - not 1,0. So after last used row in column F but in column G. Could you please revise code to do that? It would help me a lot.

Comment: If you never add another entry to column F the last row will always be the same and you will never see all of the values as it will just overwrite them.  You will have to add something to the end of column F to print out all of the values.

Comment: Step through the code and watch how it updates the worksheet to see an example of what I am talking about.

Comment: Maybe I just realized what you were trying to tell me. I have updated my answer accordingly. See if that is better.

Comment: Mate, I love you! That's it. Thank you so much.